# MFMailComposeViewController crashes when trying to edit email body in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

I have an App that supports both iOS 5 and iOS 6.
MFMailComposeViewController works fine in iOS 6 but I have a crash in iOS 5 when a user tries to edit the body of the email. All other fields can be edited without any problems. 
Has anybody seen this problem?

The code is as follows:

```
// Displays an email composition interface inside the application. Populates all the Mail fields.
-(void)displayMailComposerSheet {
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject:@"xyz"];

    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"support@xyz.com"];
    [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

    [picker setMessageBody:@"xyz" isHTML:NO];

    // Deprecated in iOS 6.0:
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

// Dismisses the email composition interface when users tap Cancel or Send. Proceeds to update the 
// message field with the result of the operation.
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller 
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {

    // Deprecated in iOS 6.0:
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The crash log looks as follows:

```
Crashed Thread:  0

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
iPhone Simulator 358.4, iPhone OS 5.1 (iPhone/9B176)

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MFComposeTextContentView setInputAccessoryView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d6b880'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1da6022 0x1b19cd6 0x1da7cbd 0x1d0ced0 0x1d0ccb2 0x5e4b1 0xb5aa29 0x1d71855 0x1d71778 0xa9f19a 0xaabb03 0x49e084 0x169a798 0x4658fb 0x4675f8 0x45fe29 0x45f133 0x4603bf 0x462a21 0x46297c 0x45b3d7 0x1c01a2 0x1c0532 0x1a6dc4 0x19a634 0x1f39ef5 0x1d7a195 0x1cdeff2 0x1cdd8da 0x1cdcd84 0x1cdcc9b 0x1f387d8 0x1f3888a 0x198626 0x303d 0x2f65)

abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x99b6e9c6 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x991a5f78 pthread_kill + 106
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x99196bdd abort + 167
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x027dee78 abort_message + 50
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x027dc89e _ZL17default_terminatev + 34
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x01b19f17 _objc_terminate + 94
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x027dc8de _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 13
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x027dc946 std::terminate() + 23
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x027ddb3e __cxa_rethrow + 83
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x01b19e15 objc_exception_rethrow + 47
10  CoreFoundation                  0x01cdcde0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 304
11  CoreFoundation                  0x01cdcc9b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
12  GraphicsServices                0x01f387d8 GSEventRunModal + 190
13  GraphicsServices                0x01f3888a GSEventRun + 103
14  UIKit                           0x00198626 UIApplicationMain + 1163
15  SomeXYZApp                      0x0000303d main + 141 (main.m:16)
16  SomeXYZApp                      0x00002f65 start + 53
```

Comment: Just to clarify MFComposeTextContentView is an object within MFMailComposeViewController. Instance 0x8d6b880 is indeed MFComposeTextContentView. For whatever reason is getting the selector setInputAccessoryView which is causing the crash. All this is happening on the internals of the MFMailComposeViewController class.

Answer (score 1):

1 Create mail account if you try to do this on device

2 MFMailComposeViewController  contain methon "canSendMail, so you could try:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
 // create mail
} else {
// error message
}
```

3 Try to call controller in main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //call MFMailComposeViewController
});
```

Comment: Steps 1 & 2 are already part of my code. Tried step 3 but no change. I do get the MailCompose view, the crash occurs when trying to edit the email body as if the first responder was sent to the wrong object.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Only in IOS6, not in IOS5.1. 
Testing learned that the form wasn't released properly. Therefore I added code to force the release of the form . That worked in my case. Hope it helps you as well.

```
-(void) sendMail:(NSString *) mailTo
{
    // Check if you can send an e-mail
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        @try
        {
            // show the form
            MFMailComposeViewController *mailForm = nil;
            mailForm = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            mailForm.mailComposeDelegate = self;
            [mailForm setToRecipients:@[ mailTo ]];
            mailForm.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
            mailForm.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
            [self presentModalViewController:mailForm animated:YES];
        }

        @catch (NSException *exception)
        {
            // Show what went wrong
            NSString *fout = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@: %@",[exception name], [exception reason]];
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Mailer" message:fout delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Inform the user you cannot send mail, no mailbox set
        [self noEmailAccountMeansNoEmail];
    }
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)mailForm didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    // Get the mail form off the screen 
    if ((mailForm != nil))
        [mailForm dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    // Force release/dealloc of the screen
    mailForm = nil;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this again may be you forgot small thing...i am not sure abt that.....you code looks fine.... it should work..

First add and Import the MessageUI Framework

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
```

and Declare the MFMaileComposeViewControllerDelegate

```
@interface MailViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

Write this code for sending the mail

```
- (IBAction)openMail:(id)sender 
{
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [mailer setSubject:@"xyz"];

    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fisrtMail@example.com", @"secondMail@example.com", nil];
    [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];

    NSString *emailBody = @"xyz";

    [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    [self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];

    [mailer release];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure"
                                                    message:@"Your device doesn't support the composer sheet"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

}

and also write the delegate method of MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{   
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled: you cancelled the operation and no email message was queued.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved: you saved the email message in the drafts folder.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail send: the email message is queued in the outbox. It is ready to send.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail failed: the email message was not saved or queued, possibly due to an error.");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Mail not sent.");
            break;
    }

        // Remove the mail view
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Nope. This is basically what I have. As I mentioned before, I get the MailComposer view displayed. So all the checks and balances have been done. I can tap on all the entries in the view except the body of the email. I can even send the email if the body is unchanged. Only when one tries to edit the body the App crashes, and this happens only on devices running iOS 5.

Comment: in your email body.......what you are showing........? it is HTML or Simple text....?

Comment: I am showing simple text. Changing the HTML setting does not change the crashing outcome. And yes, I am using ARC.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. I am using DAKeyboardControl which allows scrolling dismissal of the keyboard (see [GitHub for DA's KeyboardControl](https://github.com/danielamitay/DAKeyboardControl)).

When responderDidBecomeActive in DA's code gets called through an MFMailComposeViewController, textField receives a MFComposeTextContentView object which does not respond to inputAccessoryView. This seems to be an interaction which is not supported. However note that in iOS 6 this problem does not occur as DA's overloaded classes are not called by MFMailComposeViewController.

If DAKeyboardControl support is removed, everything works correctly.

Comment: Latest version of Daniel's code fixes this issue. Thanks Daniel!